# Use TwitterOAuth in array

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I'm using twitter OAuth (by Abraham), there's a function that I'd like to repeat multiple times in a page using PHP. I have a database set up with a list of user's auth keys and secrets setup with the information:

```
Table Name: twitter
Fields: id, key, secret (primary - id, with auto_increment)
```

I need to make it so that create a new connection for each of those keys. And to do this I must use the function

```
$connection = new TwitterOAuth(APP KEY, APP SECRET, USER KEY, USER SECRET);
```

Originally, I typed out each time in an array such as `$connection['0']`, `$connection['1']`, etc...

Using mySQL, I receive an error telling me I can't make the function in an array, so coding geniuses, how do you suppose I go about this?

By the way here's my code:

```
$con=mysqli_connect("host","username","password","twtid");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM twitter");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $connection = new TwitterOAuth(KEY, SECRET, $row['key'], $row['secret']);
}
```

Error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type TwitterOAuth as array in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not putting the objects in an array, you're just overwriting the same variable each time through the loop with a different `TwitterOAuth` object. Try this:

```
$connection = array()
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $connection[$row['id']] = new TwitterOAuth(KEY, SECRET, $row['key'], $row['secret']);
}
```