# Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object in /xxxx/xxxxx/xxxx.php on line 46

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

I have code which takes keys and secrets list from a database, the structure was described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20694721/use-twitteroauth-in-array/20694926). Anyways, when I try to submit the form and get favourites using the list, it gives me the error listed above (Call to a member function post() on a non-object) and I'm unsure why. Anyways here's my code, see any errors?

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * User has successfully authenticated with Twitter. Access tokens saved to session and DB.
 */
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
$con=mysqli_connect("host","user","pass","twtid");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM twitter");
$connection = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)){
    $connection[$row['id']] = new TwitterOAuth(key, secret, $row['key'], $row['secret']);
}


/* Create a TwitterOauth object with consumer/user tokens. */
/* $content = $access_token['oauth_token']. " " . $access_token['oauth_token_secret']; */
/* $content = $connection->get("account/verify_credentials"); */

$url1 = parse_url($_POST['url'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$url = explode("/", $url1);

 /* If method is set change API call made. Test is called by default. */
$method = 'statuses/retweet/'.$url[3];
$amt = rand(10,15);
$sub = rand(1,2);
$amt1 = $amt-$sub-1;
for ($x=0; $x<=$amt; $x++)
   {
    if($_POST['retweet'] == "Retweet"){
        $content = twitteroauth_row($method, $connection[$x]->post($method), $connection[$x]->http_code);
    }

    if($x == 9) {
        $done = "yes";
    }
}

for ($x1=0; $x1<=$amt1; $x1++)
   {
if($_POST['favorite'] == "Favourite"){
$content = $connection[$x1]->post('favorites/create', array('id' => $url[3]));  
}

   }
}
```

Comment: Pretty obvious: `$connection[$x1]` doesn't exist for that value of $x1

Comment: Mark, it should exist because in my database the id's go up to 18. And taking a random number 10-15, it should exist.

Comment: just because it exists in your db, doesn't mean that the `new Twitteroauth` call actually returned a valid object. you will have assigned SOMETHING to that slot in the array, but the error message states quite clearly that it's **NOT** an object